# A splitting field for a finite group can be chosen as a finite extension

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

L. C. Grove, Groups and Characters, Proposition 5.1.12, p. 105, states : Let $G$ be a finite group, let $F$ be a field whose characteristic doesn't divide the order of $G$; there is a finite extension of $F$ that is a splitting field for $G$.

I don't understand the proof given by L. C. Grove, which is as follows : Let $L$ be an algebraic closure of $F$. By Corollary 5.1.5, $L$ is a splitting field for $G$. Let $\{T_{1}, \ldots , T_{k}\}$ be a full set of inequivalent irreducible (hence absolutely irreducible) L-matrix representations of $G$. When $g$ runs over $G$ and $i$ runs over $\{1, \ldots , k\}$, the matrix entries run over a finite set of elements of $L$. Since the elements of $L$ are algebraic over $F$, there is a finite extension $K$ of $F$ that contains all matrix entries.

So far, so good. But the proof ends with the assertion that $K$ is a splitting field for $G$ since all $T_{s}$ are $K$-representations. I don't see how this implies that $K$ is a splitting field for $G$.

I. M. Isaacs, Character Theory of Finite Groups, 9.10, p. 148, gives a proof which needs much more machinery.

What do you think ? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: The definition of a splitting field of a group $G$ is [there](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_field). What I know is that if you have an injective homomorphism $\phi : G \to GL_n(F)$ then $K= F[\phi(g_1),\ldots]$ is a finite field extension, and we have an injective homomorphism $G \to K^\times$. It seems they are doing the same with each ireducible $F$-representation of $G$.

Comment: You have written all absolutely irreducible representations of $G$ over the field $K$, so $K$ is a splitting field for $G$ by definition. I am not seeing the problem here!

Comment: I must confess that I don't understand your comment. If it is so simple, why does I. M. Martin give such an elaborate proof ?

Comment: Instead of "I.M. Martin", please read "I.M. Isaacs".

Comment: I'm puzzled. The proof of (9.10) in Isaacs' book looks pretty much identical to Grove's proof to me. What "much more machinery" do you think it needs?

Comment: Theorem .9.9, which relies on corollary 9.7,which relies on theorem 9.6, and so on.

Comment: I think that the reason Isaacs appears to be making more of a meal of it is that he's proving something more general: unlike Grove he doesn't assume that the field characteristic doesn't divide the group order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a difficulty now. You really need to prove that an irreducible representation $T$ over $K$ remains irreducible as an $L$-representation. If you can prove that, then it is absolutely irreducible over $L$ and hence also over $K$. If not, then  it would be equivalent over $L$ to a direct sum of representations, each of which could be written over $K$. If the fields are infinite then it is proved in Proposition 5.1.6 of the book by Grove that, if two $K$-representations are equivalent over $L$ then they are equivalent over $K$, and so this cannot happen

Prop 5.6 is also true for finite fields, but not proved in the book.
You could still complete the proof of Prop 5.1.12 by adjoining finitely many extra elements from $L$ to $K$ to enable $T$ to be equivalent to a direct sum of smaller representations. So after finitely many extensions of $K$ of this kind, the result would eventually hold.

Comment: Thanks. I think there is no more problem.